# Monitoring the Evaluation of NDSolve: time to finish estimation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

My problem is quite simple: I run a `NDSolve` with a system of many ODEs, a calculation that will run for many hours, and I would like to know the progress of the calculation while it goes on.

More precisely, calling `f[n][t]` the functions to be solved in the interval `{tin,tfin}`, It will be sufficient to print at regular intervals `t` the value of `Sum[f[n][t]]` for example, and possibly to save them as well. As a side effect, this will also give me an idea of when the calculation is going to end.

However I don't want to sacrifice a significant amount of runtime for this monitoring. One option could be really to split the calculation in intervals (a table of `NDSolve`) and print the intermediate results at each point. But I am afraid to have a significant overhead due to the reconstruction of the system of equations every time (I also use the method `"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"` which I believe transforms symbolically the system before integrating it) so I hope that some wizards among you could help me out providing an efficient solution to this problem using perhaps `EvaluationMonitor` or `EventLocator` or `StateData` ?

Any example will be appreciated.

EDIT: here is an example I just invented (the real example is more complicated).

```
M = 100;
Clear[P];
eqns := Table[
   P[k]'[t] == -(1/k) P[k][t] - 
     P[k][t]^2 Sum[Exp[-(k - q)^2/M] P[q][t], {q, 1, M}]
   , {k, 1, M}];

initial = Table[P[k][0] == 0.2, {k, 1, M}];

spos = NDSolve[Join[{eqns, initial}], 
   Table[P[k], {k, 1, M}], {t, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3];
```

Comment: A (simplified) version of your problem would be most helpful to us for helping you solve your problem...

Comment: Ok edited! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

OK, I'd start with something simple like:

```
showStatus[status_] := 
  LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
   SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
    ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
```

and use an `EvaluationMonitor` like this:

```
spos = NDSolve[{eqns, initial}, Table[P[k], {k, 1, M}], {t, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, PrecisionGoal -> 3,
   AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]]
```

As side note an alternative:

```
tEnd = 100;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[currentTime], {0, tEnd}]
(* and ..., EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;) *).
```

To use a state object you could use the following:

Start with `ProcessEquations` which will do as much as possible for the pre processing.

```
{state} = 
 NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqns, initial}, 
  Table[P[k], {k, 1, M}], {t, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, PrecisionGoal -> 3,
   AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

The generates state object can then be used with `Iterate` which you can give a second argument until when it should iterate. The you could use a `Table` or some such (`Do`) to iterate over the intermediate halt points.

```
Table[NDSolve`Iterate[state, i]; Print[i], {i, 0, 100, 10}];
```

Note that you could also specify something like this:

```
Table[..., {i, {1,7,8,9,17,45,99}}]
```

to generate arbitrary stop points. Not sure how useful that is though, since if you are a point in time `tp` that does not allow you to conclude when `tEnd` will be reached.

To get the solution you post process the state object like this:

```
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]
```

Note that you can do much with NDSolve state objects, like reinitializing. You find more on the topic of NDSolve state objects in the Components and Data structure section of [tutorial/NDSolveOverview](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html)

Comment: is there a good reason why you don't just use the documented `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],WindowStatusArea->status]` but the undocumented `LinkWrite[_,SetNotebookStatusLine[...]]`? I have a suspicion but am not sure...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, no not really, it's just that old habits die hard. I have never used the documented one, so I would not know about possible issues.